# AngularJS Smilies module produces "undefined" at first choose

Tags: angularjs

I use this module [AngularJS smilies](http://mistic100.github.io/angular-smilies/) to show smilies in my chat.
It works fine except the first time I choose a smilie with the smilie picker. 
Than I get an "undefined" text and afterwards the shortcut of the smilie is printed. 
My question now would be how to prevent the **undefined** at first choose?

[image: AngularJS Smilies - undefined]

Comment: On your ```input``` field, what are you passing in for ```ng-model```?

Comment: That was the right hint - Thanks a lot! The model was not initialized.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear. I've written up the solution to your question, and submitted it as an answer. Just in case any future users encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for [AngularJS Smilies](http://mistic100.github.io/angular-smilies/):

Their example case for the `input` field:

```
<input ng-model="message" focus-on-change="message" class="form-control">
```

Their example uses `$scope.message` as the default value for the field. *In your controller* make sure that the value you pass into `ng-model` is initialized, otherwise the *Smilies Directive* will start with the value of `undefined`.